# Insert 36 char hash in mysql

Tags: mysql, hash

how can I generate a hash like this in mysql? Can I do it with INSERT statement?

00ee2f7f-4ead-4aaa-b29c-cc3f07ee2e94

I would like to add more records to a database, but I'm learning mysql now, and have no idea, how to generate something like this. Can it happen, that the same ID is generated?
Thx in advance!

Comment: What exactly is this ID, other than a specific string pattern of random alphanumeric characters in groups of presumably fixed length?

Comment: It's called Globally Unique Identifier (GUID) or Universally Unique Identifier (UUID). MySQL has a function called `UUID()` that generates it. In theory, it can't happen that you get two of the same.

Comment: The ID is a primary key in a table.

Comment: N.B: whats the statement I can generate something like this with?

Comment: @N.B. If the input data is exactly the same, and the algorithm is the same, then the outcome would be the same.

Comment: @N.B. Is impossible to have an unlimited number of distinct char sets, using a limited number of chars and limited set lenght.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tableName (columnName) VALUES(UUID());`? And as @N.B. mentioned, this will most likely not cause duplicate values as you enter data

Comment: @DannyThunder - please research GUID / UUID theory before replying. Also, where have you read in the question and my comment anything about input, algorithm and anything like that? Please, read before trying to show off your "knowledge".

Comment: @zozo - GUID isn't a character really, same as DannyThunder - feel free to enter "GUID" or "UUID" in google and read before replying.

Comment: @N.B. Well hello to you too! Where did he state that it is GUID / UUID? He just gave us a formatted string. You made that assumption, not me. Hence, it can be duplicated.

Comment: OK thanks for all the help, I know what to check now!

Comment: @DannyThunder - it's obvious that Joey is someone who *saw* such a string and doesn't know what's it called. To a trained eye it's pretty obvious what's needed, if you feel the desire to argue and flame - 4chan is your site, have fun. Meanwhile, if you have no intention to help - no need to stick around.

Comment: @N.B.: Exactly. I tried to look it up everywhere, but I'm not sure how its generated. I'm learning this stuff now, thatswhy I'm so stupid, that I can't even ask a question properly. But you guys pointed me at the right direction. Thanks again.

Comment: @Joey - you simply invoke MySQL's function called `UUID()`. If you insert into the table it's `INSERT INTO table (your_column) VALUES (UUID())` or if you want to just select it and display it - `SELECT UUID()`. It's actually that easy :) also note that PHP doesn't have the same capabilities for generating a UUID like MySQL does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are lots of ways of generating the ID. That depends on what you need.

Yes it can happen the same id is generated. For the simple fact that you have an unlimited number of entries, and for each you use a 36 chars id (that is a limited number). So when you reach the end of the possibilities, one that was already generated will be generated again.

Also I presume you use mysql with something else (php maybe?), you can generate it there also.

Note: The more precise you describe what you need, the better answers you'll get.

Comment: Yes, I'm using php to generate it in mysql.

Comment: Then you can generate there whatever you need... if you post what you need maybe we can help.

Comment: What zozo forgot to say is that the number of possibilities you have is `5,316,911,983,139,663,491,615,228,241,121,400,000` so yes, good luck exceeding that. Now, the easiest way of generating an ID is to use auto_incrementing number. Every next one will be unique. The reason UUID/GUID is used is due to having clusters of databases where each database might generate the same number, but definitely won't generate the same GUID. Since you accepted this answer, I want to put it as a comment that the way you generate it is `SELECT UUID()` or `INSERT INTO table (your_column) VALUES (UUID())`.

Comment: @N.B. Please post it as an answer... He can still change his choice in the first day. Although nowhere in question was specified, it was a good catch. Regarding the number of possibilities, I was not arguing the fact  that you need to exceed that, I was arguing the fact that you said it was unique while it wasn't, also I stated one example that generates same strings. You don't need to exceed that number. Anyway since the question was answered... doesn't matter any more so have a great day.

Comment: @zozo - I'm fine with you adding extra info to your answer, it's easier for people who google and stumble upon this answer to catch desired info in one solid answer rather than having to skim trough more of them :) also, have a nice and great day :)